# OpenSSO SSOToken to SAML assertion and back

Tags: web-services, single-sign-on, token, saml, opensso

I'm considering securing a whole Java EE software platform with *OpenAM* (prev. Sun OpenSSO). Applications - running on WebLogic AS - would be secured by a *JEE Policy Agent* and web services with *WS-Security SAML Token Profile*.

As of my understanding, the *SSOTokenManager* enables application code to retrieve OpenAM's SSO token. But in order to invoke the *SAML* protected Web Services, I need to obtain a SAML Assertion from OpenAM. *Can anybody tell me how to do so ?*

Also, in the Web Service code, I may need to get back a SSO Token from a SAML assertion. *Is that possible ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve both conversions using OpenSSO's [Security Token Service](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-3748/ggjtc?l=en&a=view). There is a [tutorial](http://wikis.sun.com/display/ISE/ISE+OpenSSO+STS) for configuring it.

Answer (score 1):

The SSOToken is an internal OpenAM representation of a users session, whilst a SAML token is an asserted identity with associated information. As such, these are not directly translatable in the way you describe.

In order to obtain a SAML token for use in your web service call, you should look at the STS functionality in OpenAM. The is a standardised service that will authenticate users and then make an assertion about the identity and authentication of the user, represented by a SAML token. This token is then returned to the calling entity (the web service client) who can include this token as per the relevant WS-* standards.

You may also want to look at the OpenAM wss provider or the Metro/WSIT library to assist implementation on the client side.

Comment: By internal representation, does it imply the SSOToken should not be persisted on / used by the client to ensure single sign on?